# How to create and deploy AWS lambda from boto3 for node.js app in python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I am uploading NodeJS file to s3 bucket now I want to run the node.js files uploaded to s3 bucket
Here is my current code:

```
s3=boto3.client('s3', zone,aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key,aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_key)
with open(generatedfolder1+"package.json", "rb") as f:
   s3.upload_fileobj(f, bucket, gendirname+'/package.json')
with open(generatedfolder1+"index.js", "rb") as f:
   s3.upload_fileobj(f, bucket, gendirname+'/index.js')
```

Comment: S3 is a storage service.  Are you looking for an AWS [compute service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/aws-overview/compute-services.html)?

Comment: @fedonev aws lambda works with s3 storage but now i want to make it work programmatically and there is library called boto3 which allows to this. The thing is Information is very limited and articles which shows how to do it are paid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your goal is to deploy a Lambda programatically.  Use the boto3 Lambda client's [create_function](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.create_function) API to do this.  The Lambda service indeed uses S3 to store the function artefacts, but you wouldn't typically interact with S3 directly.  The docs have a step-by-step `create-function` [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-awscli.html) using the CLI. The CLI uses boto3 under the hood.

FYI, [boto3](https://github.com/boto/boto3) is simply the original project name of the AWS SDK for Python.  There are [other AWS language SDKs](https://aws.amazon.com/developer/tools/), including the [AWS SDK for JavaScript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/index.html).  In the JS SDK, you'd create your Lambda with the [CreateFunctionCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-lambda/classes/createfunctioncommand.html) class.  All the SDKs do the same things, but only the Python SDK has a great nickname!